# Search in favorite questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, bookmarks

It would be nice to have an advanced search option to limit the results to questions that I have marked as "favorite".  At the moment I have too many pages of favorite questions to practically sort through them all to find anything.  Should I have fewer favorites or is this something others would find useful?

Answer (score 3):

This is [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) on the main meta, so it might happen someday: [Search in list of favorited questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-list-of-favorited-questions)

---

Circa Jan 6 '13, this feature was implemented.